# nest client and service -- clarification

Tags: nest-api

I have created a nest client with refrence to this link.

https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/register-client

Now this link use to say client have user :---
"after a client is created, then your users will be notified when you update the client"

1> So what exactly a NEST client is ? Is it a mobile or HTML app which can control NEST devices ?

2> What exaclty is the meaning of users in above statement ? Is it means suppose there are 5 members of the house, so there are 5 users ?

3> mostly the client server model is like this :--

```
   html/mobile app  <---->  NEST service  <-----> NEST devices
```

Suppose my home have 5 NEST devices & i want to control them.
   Now where will this NEST service will exist :--
   a> will it be in be in a standalone Embedded device running in my home, connected to internet MODEM at one end & NEST devices at other end ?
   b> or NEST service will be running on cloud server. where my mobile app & NEST devices can get update & set the desired value for NEST device in JSON object ?

Comment: please anyone who can clarify these points ..!!

Answer (score 1):

1)Client is an "adaptor" for the app you're going to create using the Nest API. 
2)Users in this case are the tokens you get per each user of your app. For more details see [access tokens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_token) in Wiki. To answer the second part of the question: If each of the 5 members has a different version of the app you developed with the Nest API and they try connecting to one of your Nest accounts then each of them will create a connection using an access token and will be counted as a "user". To read more, check out ["How your users experience Works with Nest"](https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/how-users-wwn/)and ["User Limits"](https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/user-limits/)

3)Yes and no, you can see how it works [here](https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/about/) and [here](https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/design-wwn/). This should answer a) and b) as you can have app to cloud Works With Nest connections and cloud to cloud.